# In the expression bool << integer, is bool promoted to int, or to the same type as the integer?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

Consider the following code:

```
// E1 << E2 with E1 bool, and E2 an integer
true << static_cast<char>(1);
true << static_cast<short int>(1);
true << static_cast<int>(1);
true << static_cast<unsigned int>(1);
true << static_cast<long long int>(1); 
true << static_cast<long long unsigned int>(1);
```

When doing the operation, is `E1` promoted as the same type as `E2`, or is it promoted first to `int` and then to `std::common_type<E1, E2>::type`?

In other words, is:

```
true << static_cast<char>(9);
```

defined, or undefined behaviour ?

Comment: C doesn't really have a "bool" type. C99 adds `_Bool`, but it's effectively an `int` with the acceptable values of `1` or `0`. This question is only about C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [expr.shift]:

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

From [conv.prom]:

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

Integral promotion on `bool` produces `int`. So the result type of `true << (any integral type)` is `int`. `true << static_cast<char>(9)` after integral promotion is the same as `1 << 9`, which is well-defined as `512`.

Comment: And what happen for `true << 60ULL`?

Comment: @Vincent Undefined behavior... `1 x 2^60` cannot be represented in `unsigned int`.

Comment: Ok, so `true + (1ULL << 60ULL)` is defined, but not `true << 60ULL`. I was not aware of that.