# Are bitwise and logical operations the same for bool type?

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

C++ has logical operations, `!a`, `a && b`, `a || b` applicable to true/false values.
And it has bitwise operations, applicable to all (integer?) types, `~a`, `a & b`, `a | b`, `a ^ b`, (`a << N`, `a >> N`).
Together with in place mutation operators, `a &= b`, `a |= b`, `a ^= b`, (`a <<= b`, `a >>= b`).

What confuses me is that bitwise operations could be acting on bits of `bool` that are not at all part of the true/false value.
Even doing unnecessary bit operations.
I guess that last fact makes bitwise shifting undefined for `bool` and that makes me doubt whether all bitwise operations are valid at all.

So, are these equivalent *for bool types*? `~a == !a`, `a && b == a & b`, `a || b == a | b`?

For some reason (won't question here) there is no "in-place" *logical* mutation operators (i.e. `a &&= b`, `a ||= b`).

This inspires these questions, are these other bitwise operations valid on bools themselves? are `a &= b` and `a |= b` always equivalent to `a = a && b` and `a = a || b` respectively?** (no "in-place" xor `a = a ^ b`?)

Some examples: https://godbolt.org/z/hcccG8c9o

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32800866/104458

Comment: @selbie, I extrapolate that in any bitwise operation `bool` is promoted to `int` (why not `char`?), and that gives a path to evaluate a response to my questions. Which I guess is positive in all cases but I am bad to take into account corner cases.

Comment: except for short circuit behavior.

Comment: trial and error shouldnt be the last but it can be the first step to understanding. I don't quite understand your asserts. You can compare bit and bool side by side:  https://godbolt.org/z/jsE6bdhqd. What you said, promotion to integer messes up `~`

Comment: yep, I don't understand completelly why. It is not a matter of converting back to `bool` even. https://godbolt.org/z/nd1h1P1M4

Comment: @alfC -- re "why not `char` -- **all** integer types that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`, but that's not relevant here) when they are used in expressions. So promoting `bool` to `char` would just be an extra step on the way to `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(For simplicity I will assume C++20, i.e. two's complement representation of integer types. What I am writing may technically not hold prior to C++20 for all theoretically possible conforming representations of integer types.)

> What confuses me is that bitwise operations could be acting on bits of bool that are not at all part of the true/false value.

The built-in bitwise operations have the [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) applied to their operands first. For integral operands that implies [*integral promotions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion): Operands with a conversion rank below that of `int` are converted to `int` first (or `unsigned int` or a higher rank integral type if `int` can't hold all values of the original type).

The promotion always leaves the original value unchanged. In the case of `bool`, `true` is mapped to `1` and `false` to `0`. So the result after promotion will have its least significant bit either set or unset, while all other bits are unset. Also, there are always at least `15` such bits, because `int` must be at least 16 bit wide.

As a consequence `~a == !a` is always false. `~` will set these additional bits, while promotion of `!a` will not. However `bool(~a) == bool(!a)` is `true` only if `a` is `false`, because with additional bits set `bool(~a)` is always `true`.

`a && b == a & b` is always true, because additional bits will be zero when `&` is applied.

`a || b == a | b` is always true, because additional bits will again remain zero.

However, if `a` and `b` are actual expressions, then there is another difference in that the logical operators short-circuit evaluation, while the bitwise ones don't. Therefore, the side effects may be different.

Also, the result of the logical operators will be a `bool`, while that of the bitwise ones will be a `int`. Therefore they are not interchangeable as they might e.g. affect overload resolution where their result is used.

Also, this applies only for the built-in operators. If any overloaded operators are involved, nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: I had the feeling that there was some counterintuitive case. ~a not equivalent to !a is very much so.

Comment: "If any overloaded operators are involved, nothing is guaranteed." , that is exactly the origin of my question, it was to implement operator overloading in a way that is logically (and/or bitwise) consistent.

Comment: @alfC In terms of value you are basically good with `&` and `|`, but not `~`. Still, the short-circuit behavior is significant, as is the fact that the compound assignment operators evaluate the left-hand side only _once_.

Comment: @alfC I would not attempt to change the meaning of bitwise and logical operators to fit one paradigm. That's very counter-intuitive. Either keep the standard meaning or don't overload the ones not matching the paradigm you want to follow.

Comment: I abuse operator overloading often, (including (unary) `&`, `~`, and `,`) (I can point you to these). But as much as I do that, I never overload `&&`, `||` because I deem that as "impossible"/"always wrong" because logical shortcutting cannot be simulated by operator overloading.

Comment: operator overloading is a cool feature until you discover that not operator overloading is pretty cool as well ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I couldn't agree more. Both are cool. If you are going to do it, you have to do it all the way: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/README.md#pointer-to-subarray

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Obviously `&(&*((~A).begin()+1))->operator()(2) == &A[2][1]`, https://godbolt.org/z/YKeK85ofo